# Is there a way to paste multiple lines to the left of multiple lines (keeping formatting) in libreoffice writer?

Tags: libreoffice, copy-and-paste

If I have these lines

1

2

3

and these lines

a**b**c

de**f**

**g**hi

Is there a way to paste them so that I get

1a**b**c

2de**f**

3**g**hi

That is to say, I want that the original bold characters (and any other formatted characters) are preserved.

Comment: Nope don't think so. That is one of the things you can do with Calc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, LibreOffice Writers offers [a feature named "Block Selection Mode"](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/02/20050000.html). You can enable it using the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. Then, you can copy content "vertically" and paste it the same way.

Generally, pasting the content of a "block copy" won't touch the formatting of the target lines, but maybe, the pasted content may acquire formatting of pre-existing, adjacent content. So, in your example, the "3" will most likely acquire bold formatting from the adjacent "g" letter.

Comment: Yeah. It works! Since I'm pasting lines that start with an unformatted dot, the preceding numbers shouldn't acquire bold formatting. Thanks.